# Getting Error when trying to undo changes in an Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement a method to undo changes on an entity. I'm using below procedure :

```
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
```

The problem is that I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` with below message :

> EntityMemberChanged or EntityComplexMemberChanged was called without
>   first calling EntityMemberChanging or EntityComplexMemberChanging on
>   the same change tracker with the same property name. For information
>   about properly reporting changes, see the Entity Framework
>   documentation.

Any idea to get around this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in below thread :

[Undo / Redo with change tracking in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022115/undo-redo-with-change-tracking-in-entity-framework)

In fact I'm using a `BindingList` as a collection. So I just set the property `RaiseListChangedEvents` to false before proceeding with Undo / Redo changes routine and restore it to true after completing.